# How to call .aspx page from a web web service(service.svc)

Tags: asp.net

I have a web service (Service.svc). Inside this web service a web method there to call MIGS (involve with internet pavement gateway) . Before call for migs, I need to load another page I created which shows the terms and conditions.

How to do this?

Comment: What does "load another page" mean in a web service scenario?

Comment: call for another page (.aspx one)

Comment: "Call for another page" is still unclear. These can be understood as "redirect the user to", "invoke some html form", "scrap the page content", ... You have to give more details if you want us to understand your question and be able to help you.

Comment: yeah, I need to redirect to a .aspx page. thanks for your advices